# tkinter how delete both checkbox and label if checked box

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, checkbox, destroy

Im trying to check a checkbox and delete both 'checked box' and 'label' with upper button. They are both created in a loop from the same list.
I've tried to build a dictionary with 'buttons' as key and 'result_of_checkboxes' as value and destroy key if value is different from ''. It doesnot work. If buttons are keys, why can't I destroy them? What is the correct approach?
Thanks in advance!

```
from tkinter import *
    
root = Tk()    
root.geometry('400x400')
    
def destroy_button():
    for key, value in dict_check_and_buttons:
        if value != '' and current_var != '':
            key.destroy()      
            current_box.destroy()    

my_friends = ['Donald', 'Daisy', 'Uncle Scrooge']
    
button1= tk.Button(root, text = "delete both if cbox is checked", command = destroy_button).pack()
    
#-----ild checkbuttons and store results in checkbutton_result list

checkbutton_result = []

for index, friend in enumerate(my_friends):
    current_var = tk.StringVar()
    current_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text= friend,
                                 variable = current_var,
                                 onvalue = friend, offvalue = ""
                                 )
    checkbutton_result.append(current_var) #append on and off results
    current_box.pack()
        
#-----build buttons and store them in buttons_list
buttons_list = []

for index, friend in enumerate(my_friends):
    buttons= tk.Button(root, text = friend).pack()
      
    buttons_list.append(buttons)
        
#-----build a dict with list to say "if  onvalue != '' destroy button"    

dict_check_and_buttons = dict(zip(buttons_list, checkbutton_result))   

root.mainloop()
```

the error is:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python\python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "<ipython-input-18-954d3a090f2c>", line 7, in destroy_button
    for key, value in dict_check_and_buttons:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

Comment: Your `buttons_list` is just a list full of `None`s - the results of calling `.pack()`, not the widgets themselves.  You need to do the `.pack()` separately, much as you did in the `checkbutton_result` loop.

Answer (score 1):

There are following issues in your code:

- ***all items in `buttons_list` are `None` due to the following line***:

```py
buttons= tk.Button(root, text = friend).pack()  # buttons is the result of pack()
```

The line should be split into two lines:

```
buttons = tk.Button(root, text=friend)
buttons.pack()
```

- ***you cannot get a (key, value) pair by iterating a dictionary***:

```
for key, value in dict_check_and_buttons:  # dict_check_and_buttons is a dictionary
    ...
```

Instead you should iterate on the result of `dict_check_and_buttons.items()`:

```
for key, value in dict_check_and_buttons.items():
    ...
```

- ***you need to call `get()` on a `tk.StringVar()`***:

```py
for key, value in dict_check_and_buttons.items():
    if value.get() != '':  # use value.get()
        key.destroy()
```

---

If you need to destroy the checkbutton as well, you need to save the checkbutton to `checkbutton_result` along with its associated variable:

```py
checkbutton_result = []

for index, friend in enumerate(my_friends):
    current_var = tk.StringVar()
    current_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text= friend,
                                 variable = current_var,
                                 onvalue = friend, offvalue = ""
                                 )
    checkbutton_result.append((current_box, current_var)) # save both checkbutton and its associated variable
    current_box.pack()
```

Then destroy the checkbutton inside `destroy_button()`:

```py
def destroy_button():
    for btn, (cb, cbvar) in dict_check_and_buttons.items():
        if cbvar.get() != '':
            btn.destroy()
            cb.destroy()
```

Comment: Dear Mr. ACW1668    thank you very much, these are new relevant concepts to me.

Answer (score 0):

With your answer I rebuild the code. It is perfect now thanks to you.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
'''
to get if checkbox is checked to use results to delete checkbox and label
'''


def destroy_button_box():
    for button_names, (ckbox, on_off) in dict_buttons_box_var.items():
        if on_off.get() != 0:
            button_names.destroy()
            ckbox.destroy()
        


my_friends = ['Donald', 'Daisy', 'Uncle Scrooge']

button1 = tk.Button(root, text="delete label if box is checked", command=destroy_button_box).pack()


checkbox_variable_list = []

box_list = []

for index, friend in enumerate(my_friends):
    #     current_var = tk.IntVar()
    current_var = tk.IntVar()
    #   current_var = tk.StringVar()
    current_box = tk.Checkbutton(root, text=friend,
                                 variable=current_var,
                                 onvalue=1, offvalue=0
                                 )

    current_box.pack()
    
    # append checkbox and 'on' or 'off' results
    checkbox_variable_list.append((current_box, current_var))

# -----build buttons and store them in buttons_list
buttons_list = []
for index, friend in enumerate(my_friends):
    button_names = tk.Button(root, text=friend)
    button_names.pack()
    
    # append buttons in loop
    buttons_list.append(button_names)

# -----build a dict with lists to use in destroy_box_button function:
dict_buttons_box_var = dict(zip(buttons_list, checkbox_variable_list))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Both in same function is even better, thanks again.

            btn.destroy()
            cb.destroy()

and   (cb, cbvar) is splendid and exciting!